# Konva.js with Redux

Tags: redux, react-redux, react-hooks, redux-thunk, react-konva

I've tried to solve it in different ways but I couldn't. Is there any simple way to use Konva.js with Redux and React Hooks.

As I read about, Konva's context mechanism is different from React-Redux. And so, even though my all App in Provider wrapper,  React child components that I used with Konva, doesn't see the wrapper.

When I apply Provider wrapper again in child component, inner the konva's Stage tag, the app didn't give any error and worked but reducer states entered the loop somehow. I believe the provider in child components does its job but after that global provider does its job again and changes reducer states as initial states.

To fix this I tried to add another reducer and store but the same again.

I kindly ask anyone who can help and also Dear Konva Contributors :) please give a new sample to use for 2021 with react hooks.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I should have just used ReactReduxContext.Consumer, as described below.

https://github.com/konvajs/react-konva/issues/311#issuecomment-454411007